# How to check an empty dictionary?

Tags: python

I have the following code. I want to write a condition if there is an empty dictionary.

```
 belongingsList = []
    for item, count in self.belongings.items():
        if count >= 1:
            belongingsList.append(item)


    return belongingsList
```

I want to return an empty list if the dictionary is empty

Comment: You can simply write `if belongings: print("non-empty")`.

Comment: And the converse works: `if not belongings: print("empty")`

Comment: will this for loop work if the dictionary is empty

Comment: Either way, you'll get an empty list if `self.belongings` is empty because there will be nothing to loop through. 

Comment: if the dictionary is empty i want to return empty list

Comment: So, use an else condition and return an empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a simple check at the beginning to see if it's empty, then return an empty list if it is. You can also use a list comprehension to simplify it so it's not so many lines:

```
def yourFunction():
    # Return an empty list if the dict is empty.
    if not self.belongings:
        return []

    # Can use a list comprehension to simplify code.    
    return [item for item, count in self.belongings.items() if count >= 1]
```

Honestly you don't even need the beginning check since if it's an empty `dict` then the list comprehension will return you an empty list like you want:

```
def yourFunction():   
    return [item for item, count in self.belongings.items() if count >= 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could check by using `len()` function, which when applied to dictionary object, will checks for the number of key-value pairs in the dictionary

```
belongingList = []
if len(belongings) == 0: # check if the dictionary is empty
    return belongingList
else:
    for item, count in self.belongings.items():
        if count >= 1:
            belongingsList.append(item)
    return belongingList
```

Another way to do it

```
belongingsList = []

if len(belongings) > 0: # check if the dictionary is not empty
    for item, count in self.belongings.items():
        if count >= 1:
            belongingsList.append(item)

return belongingsList
```

Comment: else part will return empty list ?